# Debugging amount of funds needed to deploy +network state unknown error on Ropsten

Tags: ropsten, truffle-migration

Wrote a simple contract. Attempting to deploy to testnet and get error.

`eth --testnet --fast --rpc --rpcapi eth,net,web3,personal`

truffle.js config:

```
module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
    ropsten: {
      network_id: 3,
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      from: "0xd060fa165f3ff5f506c5391aa07bc57599d053c7",
      gas: 4000000
    }
  }
};
```

then cd into my directory,

```
truffle migrate --network ropsten

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... undefined
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value
```

How do I debug what the delta between my funds & required funds for deployment is?

Why is "network status unknown" showing?

EDIT: tried with

```
geth --rpc --rpcapi eth,net,web3,personal --testnet --fast --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303" console

INFO [01-29|17:52:23] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.7.2-stable/darwin-amd64/go1.9.2
INFO [01-29|17:52:23] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/Users/quantum/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth/chaindata cache=128 handles=1024
INFO [01-29|17:52:23] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 3 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: true EIP150: 0 EIP155: 10 EIP158: 10 Byzantium: 1700000 Engine: ethash}"
INFO [01-29|17:52:23] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/Users/quantum/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [01-29|17:52:23] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/Users/quantum/.ethash                              count=2
INFO [01-29|17:52:23] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=3
INFO [01-29|17:52:23] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash=419410…ca4a2d td=1048576
INFO [01-29|17:52:23] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash=419410…ca4a2d td=1048576
INFO [01-29|17:52:23] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash=419410…ca4a2d td=1048576
INFO [01-29|17:52:23] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [01-29|17:52:23] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [01-29|17:52:23] Starting P2P networking
INFO [01-29|17:52:25] UDP listener up                          self=enode://97d8bd87fff8bce0721e6ac15e967ac36f0b238bf44605db363c1fd73ef4860edb0c22f68da3c476d456624f5f3b9da29205f10a5c058f66c5d607282b208544@[::]:30303
INFO [01-29|17:52:25] RLPx listener up                         self=enode://97d8bd87fff8bce0721e6ac15e967ac36f0b238bf44605db363c1fd73ef4860edb0c22f68da3c476d456624f5f3b9da29205f10a5c058f66c5d607282b208544@[::]:30303
INFO [01-29|17:52:25] IPC endpoint opened: /Users/quantum/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc
INFO [01-29|17:52:25] HTTP endpoint opened: http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

Comment: Just a guess, may be you should use different ip from a localhost. You should try some of the [bootnodes ip](https://github.com/ethereum/ropsten#ropsten-testnet-pow-chain).

Comment: Where are those listed? Why would local geth not work?

Comment: Just click a link in the end of my first comment. Is your local geth synced to ropsten?

Comment: I try that, please see edit. How can I determine if network is synced or not? It says the P2P connection has started

Comment: `web3.eth.blockNumber` or `web3.eth.syncing` in your geth console. You can see current block number on ropsten network [here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/).

Comment: Nope, it's not syncing -- I thought the original geth command would automatically sync?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72419/discussion-between-roman-frolov-and-quantumpotato).